# Put command result in variable within makefile target

Tags: bash, make

I am trying to install something in tomcat webapp. This is beginning of my `install` target:

```
tomcat=`locate --regex "^(/var/lib/tomcat[0-9]{1,2}/webapps/[^/]+/)AppName\.html$" -l 1 | tr -d "\n"`
echo "Tomcat: $tomcat"
# If the string is empty (no path matched) or the path does not exists (that should never really happen)
# terminate
if [ -z "$tomcat" ] || [ ! -f "$tomcat" ]; then 
  echo "Application not found on filesystem."
  exit 404
fi
```

However this is the output:

```
tomcat=`locate --regex "^(/var/lib/tomcat[0-9]{1,2}/webapps/[^/]+/)AppName\.html -l 1 | tr -d "\n"`
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:77: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Everyone else claims that you can use `` ` `` (backtick) to assign command `stdout` output into variable. I even used `tr -d "\n"` to delete all newline characters, may they appear. And the code works flawlessly in shell:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~$ tomcat=`locate --regex "^(/var/lib/tomcat[0-9]{1,2}/webapps/[^/]+/)AppName\.html$" -l 1 | tr -d "\n"`
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~$ echo $tomcat
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/websight/AppName.html
```

What else is there to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` signs are notorious in makefiles for causing trouble because they are interpreted as variable markers. Here just doubling the one in the first line should do the trick:

```
AppName\.html$$"
```

Also have a look at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile) to learn more about makefile escaping issues.

Comment: There's one other problem probably related to `$` sign: `echo "Tomcat: $tomcat"` acts as `echo "Tomcat: omcat"` in the output. Doubling the sign produced just `Tomcat: $tomcat`, but I need to retrieve the variable...

Comment: @TomášZato It's often a good idea to use curly brackets for variables, so as to be clear about where the variable name ends: `${tomcat}`. Works in bash as well.

Comment: You might have to escape this `$` as well, because otherwise it will be regarded as a makefile variable instead of a bash variable.